# Kotlin Flow two dependant request but return the first

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have two functions, the first one that returns a Result with a model, and the second one that returns a Result with another model.

```
fun flow1(): Flow<Result<Model1>>
fun flow2(id: String): Flow<Result<Model2>>
```

What i want is went the flow1() call is success, then do the flow2() call and some logic when is success but at the end return the flow1() result.

And for the moment i just trying something like this:

```
       flow1().flatMapLatest { flow1Result ->

            flow1Result.onSuccess {
                flow2(it.id).map { flow2Result ->
                    flow2Result.onSuccess {
                        //Some logic
                    }
                }
            }.onFailure {
                // return error
            }
        }
```

I have two problems the first one that inside the flatMapLatest give an error because say that i return a Result instead of a Flow. And how i can return the Flow1 result?

Thank you!

Trying something similar to this response [Chain kotlin flows depends on Result state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64303904/chain-kotlin-flows-depends-on-result-state)

Comment: Why is `flow2` a Flow if it only returns one thing you care about? Shouldn't it simply be a suspend function since it returns only one thing? Otherwise, if `flow2` continually monitors something for a long time or forever (as flows typically do), then you can never return anything from `flow1` because you'll never finish collecting `flow2`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like this

```
fun main() {
    flow1().flatMapLatest { flow1Result ->
        // should return flow with flow1Result element emited
        flow1Result
            .onSuccess {
                // flow<flow1Result>, that we return 
                flow2(it.id).map { flow2Result ->
                        flow2Result
                            .onSuccess{
                                TODO("some logic")
                            }.onFailure{
                                // only emit flow1Result when flow2Result = Success
                                throw RuntimeError()
                            }
                       // convert flow<flow2Result> to flow <flow1Result>
                       flow1Result
                    }
                }
            .onFailure {
                // there can be other flow<flow1Result>
                throw RuntimeError()
            }
        }   
}
```